# Make a representative HSV image in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to create an HSV image (or maybe a coordinate map) which shows that coordinates accurately.

I am using the following code and get an image like this the result of the following code which is not what I want.

```
img = rand(200,200);
[ind_x, ind_y] = ind2sub(size(img),find(isfinite(img)));
ind_x = reshape(ind_x,size(img));
ind_y = reshape(ind_y,size(img));
ind = ind_x.*ind_y;

figure, imagesc(ind); axis equal tight xy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you quantize the HSV space (0-1) into 256 bins. There will be 256*256*256 possible colors. We could fix a dimension (say saturation) and generate the matrix. Then there will be 256*256 colors.

```
[x1,x2]=meshgrid(linspace(0,1,256),linspace(0,1,256));
img(:,:,1)=x1;
img(:,:,2)=1;  %fully saturated colors
img(:,:,3)=x2;

imgRGB=hsv2rgb(img); %for display purposes
imshow(imgRGB,[])
```

It will look different in RGB (that's where you would visualize). It looks similar to your image if you visualize HSV matrix (i.e. without converting it to RGB, but MATLAB doesn't know that its HSV)

```
imshow(img,[]);
```

The second image you have posted can be obtained with:

```
[x1,x2]=meshgrid(linspace(0,1,256),linspace(0,1,256));
img(:,:,1)=x1;
img(:,:,2)=0;
img(:,:,3)=x2;
imshow(img,[]) %visualizing HSV
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your code is producing something very close to what I need, I just need to increase the saturation. How I can do this? I mean, the output images are very smooth !

Comment: Two aspects: 1. You can increase the saturation by changing `img(:,:,2)`. I have set it to zero (last 5 lines of code), increase it, you will increase the saturation. 2. The output images can be made smoother by changing 256 to a larger value.

Comment: Actually I do not want to make the output smoother! I want to make them as sharp as those images which I posted

Comment: By any chance, do you think that increasing saturation will make output "less" smooth? If so, then no, it won't. To make the images less smooth, decrease the value from 256 (say 128 or even 64).